# bootstrap 5 ms-auto not pushing unordered list to the right in a navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, margin

I want to ask a question about ms-auto in Bootstrap 5.

I am trying to create a `navbar` with margin-start having a property of `auto` via `ms-auto` in the Bootstrap 5 documentation.

So far, my code appears as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Frontend Bootcamp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Frontend Bootcamp</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What You'll Learn</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#questions" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am expecting with `ms-auto` is as follows:

[image: Expected result with ms-auto]

But what I am actually rendering in the output is this:

[image: Resulting output.]

I am struggling to understand why `ms-auto` does not work here with the `ui` element. I thought that the list of items would shift to the far right, but it has not done so as per the desired result.

Why is my list not responding to `ms-auto`? Is there an incompatibility or an error in my code?

This source code was derived from a tutorial taken [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sosXZsdy-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add w-100 with the parent and use mx-auto instead ms-auto

Comment: Yes, this is correct for Bootstrap 4. I will accept this as the answer with mx-auto.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the CDN for Bootstrap 4, which I mistakenly accessed on the mainpage.

Using the Bootstrap 5 CDN and JS bundle resolved this matter.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Frontend Bootcamp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Frontend Bootcamp</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What You'll Learn</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#questions" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```